# Force WCF to use a existing buffers during Deserialization?

Tags: wcf, serialization, deserialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

I looked for some other topics here as well, but I didn't find a solution to my problem yet.

Imagine the following:
I've a very simple `ServiceContract` with different `OperationContracts`. One of these `OperationContracts` is a simple use-case "download a data transfer object".

The Service looks like:

```
...
[OperationContract]
DTO Download(strind Id)
...
```

Class DTO looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class DTO
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Id;

     [DataMember]
     public byte[] Data;
}
```

Of course it's very simple and it works fine, but I need to allocate the `byte[]` in DTO by myself!

My Code is part of a framework componenent and it's working in parallel under massive memory restrictions. I don't want WCF to allocate all the byte[] and I don't want the ManagedHeap to deallocate them all again. I need to share and reuse all parallel existing buffers.

So when I finished my serialization I will reuse the buffer on serverside.
On clientside I want WCF to read into **my buffer**!

I tried some solutions with own `XmlObjectSerialiers` and own `OperationBehaviors`, but it didn't work yet.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you want your Data to be included in the datacontract as member if you do not want to send it to the client?

Comment: Of course I want to send data to the client. But I want wcf to past the incoming data in my already allocated byte[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I found a first working solution using an own Serializer:XmlObjectSerializer, an own IContractBehavior and an own DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.

While reading from XmlDictionaryReader during Deserialization I use the following snippet:

```
public bool DeserializeFrom(XmlDictionaryReader source)
{
     ...
     readBytes = source.ReadElementContentAsBase64(MyOwnAlreadyAllocatedBuffer, offset, toRead);
     ...
}
```

This works, but it's still a bit slower than the DataContractSerializer.

Any other options?

Notice: I just want to transfer already binary serialized data!